# Attach Sound to an SKEmitterNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, audiotoolbox

I'm using Apple's Sprite Kit Framework and I'm wondering how I can attach a sound file to an SKEmitterNode such that every time a particle is emitted, it plays the sound.

EG: A gun shooting bullets with a bang each time the bullet (particle) is fired (emitted).

Comment: This probably is not the best way to implement shooting. How do you perform collision handling?

Comment: That's not necessary, this is essentially just for show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve desired effect you can use [particleAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/particleAction) property on the emitter to define sound playing action.

Define sound playing action using [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed%3awaitForCompletion%3a) or play sound inside a block and run it using [SKAction runBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock%3a)

Action will run every time particle is emitted.